# Salesforce: Create timer on objects - is it possible?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

The company needs to know how much time each worker spends on each part of each project part.

The following resembles some custom objects that were defined for this app:

- Custom Project
- Custom Project Part
- Custom Time Entry

Now we need to customize our salesforce app in such a way that a worker can open the project part and click "Start..." and later "Stop...".

These buttons would create a time entry with a start date and update the time entry with a stop date respectively.

Is this possible to do in the custom objects themselves? (ideal)

Should we be creating new pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Create two custom Buttons for your custom object eg. "Start" and "Stop". Then put some JavaScript to the buttons to update your custom fields:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")}

var YourCustomObject = new sforce.SObject("YourCustomObject__c");

YourCustomObject.Id = '{!YourCustomObject__c.Id }';
YourCustomObject.Start__c = '{!NOW()}';

updateStartTime = sforce.connection.update([YourCustomObject]);
```

Then insert these buttons to the page layout.

Comment: I see you're thinking about the "Creating a new page" alternative. +1 The manager seems to have grown fond of the Start/Stop button. Is there a way to create a custom field that contains start and stop dates and the way of changing them is with a start/stop button? Thanks

Comment: In my example the custom field for the start time is "Start__c" The idea is to set the time with a custom buttom at the standard page layout eg. at the project part page. No need to create a visualforce page for that.